# how to apply top and left positions according to other div with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, position

Hi I want to apply top and left position of a div according to other div position with jquery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var msg_top = jQuery(".color-cont").position().top;
var msg_left = jQuery(".color-cont").position().left;   
jQuery(".messages").css({'top': msg_top + "50px", 'left': msg_left + "50px"});
});
});
```

The html code for this is:

```
<div class="color-cont">abc def ghi</div>
<div class="messages">apply on this</div>
```

you can edit this on jsfiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/axpXU/

Answer (score 0):

last line is unnecessary , and change `msg_top  + "50px"` to `(msg_top + 50) + "px"`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var msg_top = jQuery(".color-cont").position().top;
    var msg_left = jQuery(".color-cont").position().left;   
    jQuery(".messages").css({'top': (msg_top + 50) + "px", 'left': (msg_left+50) + "px"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/axpXU/3/)

**jQuery**

```
var msg_top = $(".color-cont").position().top;
var msg_left = $(".color-cont").position().left;    
$(".messages").css({
    'top': msg_top + 50 + 'px',
    'left': msg_left + 50 + 'px'
});
```

Your code had extra `});` at end, which is why it wasn't working. And, `.position()` returns integer value. But `8 + "50px"` was concatenating and giving `850px`. Changed it to `8 + 50 + "px"`. Here `8` is value from variable `msg_...`,

[**+`.position()`**](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var msg_top = jQuery(".color-cont").position().top;    
  var msg_left = jQuery(".color-cont").position().left; 
  jQuery(".messages").css({'top': parseInt(msg_top +50)+ "px", 'left': parseInt(msg_left +    50)+"px"});
});
```

In your code, there is `});` extra and `top` and `left` return in `int`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/axpXU/4/)